# Which part is this grey pillar?

Tags: part-identification

I am wondering which set this part is from. I'm trying to make a set complete and this part clearly doesn't belong to it when I check the sets parts list.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a Lightsaber hilt (Minifigure weapon) part# 64567. The color looks like light-bluish gray in the picture, which was in 201 different sets.  You can look through the many sets on Bricklink:  (https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64567#T=C&C=86)

[image]

These are very common parts in many Star Wars sets, but come in quite a variety of different themes.

Comment: Thx for your quick answer, any idea of set name where it's used in?

Comment: Yes, I added a link for you to look through the many sets :)

Comment: Already found the set name out, thx again JohnnyB

Comment: You're welcome :)